# Where can I find a collection of a creature/character doing different actions (JSON file/ gif)?

Tags: android, user-interface, animation

Creature or Character doing actions like Hi, Sleeping, Walking, Smiling type of actions. I am looking for a collection of those in any kind of video format or gif or JSON (by which I can use it in my project) that would be helpful.  There are generic static character options available but they don't have animation.

I am looking for free options mostly, I need it to use it in my project (where that files will be used to display on home screen) which is open source

Answer (score 0):

You can download the animation in json or gif and other many formats on this link and add it to your raw directory

By The Way Its Free To Use !!

**https://lottiefiles.com/search?q=HI&category=animations***

it also has an dependencies for using it in android studio

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion'
}
```

Comment: I know about this and have already used it, but I am not able to find animation of same character/creature online